# How to display seekBar value and selected spinner item from Activity A to Activity B?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, seekbar

I have a `listView` in Activity A , which the value are returned from Activity B.When the list is clicked, it will intent to Activity B for edit.

**Activity B**

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.add_details_information);
         addItemsOnSpinner();
         if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)  // if has value pass from A
          {
              final String Project1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveProject");
              final String Description1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveDescription");
              final String Progress1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveProgress");
              final String TimeIn1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeIn");
              final String TimeOut1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveTimeOut");
              //project.setText(Project1);
              description.setText(Description1);
              //progressText.setText("Covered:")
              timeIn.setText(TimeIn1);
              timeOut.setText(TimeOut1);
              }

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
             {  // return to A

           @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
            Project=project.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Spinner Value
            Description=description.getText().toString(); //from editText
            progress=seekBar.getProgress(); // From SeekBar
            returnIntent.putExtra("Project",Project);
            returnIntent.putExtra("Description", Description);
            returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), progress+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            returnIntent.putExtra("TimeIn", TimeIn);
            returnIntent.putExtra("TimeOut",TimeOut);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
            }
           });

 public void  addItemsOnSpinner()
    {
        project=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerProject);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("TRN-XXX-XXX");
        list.add("Pro-XXX-XXX);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_item, list);
        //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        project.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**Activity A**

```
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProject", ReceiveProject);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveDescription", ReceiveDescription);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProgress", ReceiveProgress);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeIn", ReceiveTimeIn);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveTimeOut", ReceiveTimeOut);
                startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

I know that we can use `setText` to display the passed value from A to B for `editText`, but how about the `spinner` and `seekBar` value ?

This is the listView in Activity A. Value are returned from Activity B.

[image]

When listView is clicked, it will goes to B again to edit.

[image]

So how can I make the spinner in B display Pro-XXX-XXX and the seekBar goes to 48 ? Any idea or suggestion ? Thanks a lot

**Edited**

After used the answer from @Clairvoyant, now I get this (for spinner value).

**Activity A**

[image]

There are 4 list in Activity A.

Assume first list is clicked.

[image]

Everything works fine just the spinner(Project/Service/Training) display wrong value. It display the spinner value from last list(PRO-SKM-D5) instead of itself(Pro-XXX-XXX)

Comment: I already know how to set the seekbar value, but don't know how to display the selected item from spinner A to B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Step:** Make your **addItemsOnSpinner** like as below:

```
    public void addItemsOnSpinner(String value) 
    { 
     int position = 0; 
     project=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerProject); 
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

     list.add(position,"TRN-XXX-XXX"); 
     list.add("Pro-XXX-XXX"); 

     for(int i=0; i<list.size() ; i++){
         if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
             position = i;
             break;
         }
     }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_item, list); 
     //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    project.setAdapter(adapter); 

    project.setSelection(position); 
   }
```

**Second Step:** call the above method when you are assigning value to the variable you have to show in spinner here for eg: `project1` is the string value which you want to show in spinner then call the method as follows:

```
final String Project1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ReceiveProject");
 addItemsOnSpinner(Project1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences`. Next time, [googling helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962422/1390727).

**Get `SharedPreferences`**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

**Read preferences:**

```
String key = "test1_string_pref";
String default = "returned_if_not_defined";
String test1 = prefs.getString(key, default);
```

**To edit and save preferences**

```
SharedPreferences.Edtior editor = prefs.edit(); //Get SharedPref Editor
editor.putString(key, "My String");
editor.commit();
```

**Shorter way to write**

```
prefs.edit().putString(key, "Value").commit();
```

Additional info for SharedPreferences: [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [Android Developers Article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: sorry bro, I don't understand your answer

Comment: well, I already get the solution from  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19486955/5398173) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19497597/5398173). The solution are simple and easy to understand. Anyway,thanks